# How to load Instantiate object on photon server which changing sprite on generation (Sprite Synchronization)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, photon

I'm integrating photon pun in my project to show both(player 01, player 02) screens on player 01 device (same for player 02). It is almost same as split screen. Currently I'm instantiating balls on server to show on both devices. Balls are showing well but its not taking sprites, which ball prefab take randomly while generation.

I tried camera split screen previously, but its not work for me because initially i have to sync generated balls on server to show them on both player devices.

> > This is where my ball generation functions call

```
Bubble one = GetOneBubbleAtPosition(Misc.IndexToPosition(_boundRect, new 
Index(i, j)), Bubble.CharToType(c)); // Calling Instantiate bubble funtion
     one.transform.parent = _parentBalls.transform;
     _grid.Set(i, j, one);
```

> > The function where i'm Instantiating balls on server and selection of sprites on each generation

```
private Bubble GetOneBubbleAtPosition(Vector3 position, Bubble.Type type = Bubble.Type.None) // Bubble Generation Function
{
    //var go = Instantiate(ball, position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    var go = PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(Path.Combine("PhotonPrefebs", "ball") , position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    go.transform.localScale = new Vector3(25f, 25f, 1.0f);

    if (type == Bubble.Type.None)
    {
        type = Bubble.GetRandomColorFromList(_grid.GetAllUniqueTypes());
    }

    SpriteRenderer render = go.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    render.sprite = getBubbleSprite (type);

    Bubble bubble = go.GetComponent<Bubble>();
    bubble.type = type;

    return bubble;
}
```

> > This is where it takes the sprite on calling getBubbleSprite

```
private Sprite getBubbleSprite(Bubble.Type type)
{
    switch (type) {
    case Bubble.Type.Color1:
            return _bubble_1;

    case Bubble.Type.Color2:
            return _bubble_2;

    case Bubble.Type.Color3:
            return _bubble_3;

    case Bubble.Type.Color4:
            return _bubble_4;

    case Bubble.Type.Color5:
            return _bubble_5;

    case Bubble.Type.Color6:
            return _bubble_6;

    case Bubble.Type.Color7:
            return _bubble_7;

    case Bubble.Type.Color8:
            return _bubble_8;
    }

    return null;
}
```

> > This is GetRandomColorFromList function:

```
public static Type GetRandomColorFromList(List<Type> all)
{
    if (all.Count > 0)
    {
        if (all.Count == 1)
            return all[0];

        while (true)
        {
            int index = Random.Range(0, all.Count);
            if (all[index] == _lastTwo && all[index] == _lastOne)
            {
                continue;
            }

            _lastTwo = _lastOne;
            _lastOne = all[index];

            return all[index];
        }
    }

    D.warn("[Bubble] Get none type...");
    return Type.None;
}
```

> > This is GetAllUniqueTypes function:

```
public List<Bubble.Type> GetAllUniqueTypes()
{
    List<Bubble.Type> all = new List<Bubble.Type>();

    for (int i = 0; i < G.rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < G.cols; j++)
        {
            var one = _grids[i, j];

            if (one != null)
            {
                Bubble.Type type = one.type;

                if (!all.Contains(type))
                {
                    all.Add(type);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return all;
}
```

> > Last 3 functions are calling in Instantiating function
> >     I also tried to send RPC while calling the first funtion.

I expect that balls can generated on server and shows perfectly on each device.

Comment: You need to also sync the change of Sprite from server to client, this would mean something like an RPC that tells clients which object needs to change sprite and its type. Otherwise, you can create 8 different prefabs with your different sprites and spawn the correct one based on your randomization.

Comment: Yes, i have add rpc while calling 'GetOneBubbleAtPosition', but didn't worked for me :( @Saeleas

Comment: And i have facing issues in adding RPC anywhere else, because RPC needs void funtion but mine most of the function are not void, which i already mention above @saeleas

Comment: Then creating 8 different prefabs for all the types and spawning them depending on your randomization might be a solution for now. The answer from @derHugo sounds like what I was suggesting before.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Photon and its exact syntax in specific but instead of using the RPC on `GetBubbleStPosition` you should rather split it up and use the RPC on a method like

```
[PunRPC]
private void SetSprite(int viewID, int typeInt)
{
    type = (Bubble.Type) typeInt;

    var pv = PhotonView.Find(viewID);

    pv.transform.localScale = new Vector3(25f, 25f, 1.0f);

    SpriteRenderer render = pv.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    render.sprite = getBubbleSprite(type);

    Bubble bubble = pv.GetComponent<Bubble>();
    bubble.type = type;
}
```

And call it like

```
private Bubble GetOneBubbleAtPosition(Vector3 position, Bubble.Type type = Bubble.Type.None) // Bubble Generation Function
{
    //var go = Instantiate(ball, position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    var go = PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(Path.Combine("PhotonPrefebs", "ball") , position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;

    if (type == Bubble.Type.None)
    {
        type = Bubble.GetRandomColorFromList(_grid.GetAllUniqueTypes());
    }

    // The RPC call
    PV.RPC("SetSprite", RpcTarget.AllBuffered, PhotonView.Get(go).ViewID, (int)type);

    return bubble;
}
```

Thanks to @JohnTube: You can't pass your custom types without [registrating them first](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/current/reference/serialization-in-photon#custom_types). Instead simply cast the `Bubble.Type` to and from `int` and transfer that instead.

---

As said I don't know nothing about Photon, only used UNet so far. But [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/700268/send-gameobject-through-photon-rpc.html) someone says it is actually not possible to send a `GameObject` via RPC as parameter. Rather use the `PhotonView` and in the RPC call pass the `PhotonView.ViewID`.

I only know UNet and there you always had to make sure that an instantiated GameObject also has a `NetworkIentity` attached .. I guess the `PhotonView` is kind of the parallel to that so your instantiated prefab requries an attached `PhotonView` component in order to be able to identify it over the network on all clients.

Comment: Nope... when i simply calling it here **SetSprite(go, type);** , its perfectly working.
But when i add RPC **PV.RPC("SetSprite", RpcTarget.AllBuffered, go, type);** , Its not generating the balls. @derHugo

Comment: Is ot not generating them at all or not setting the sprite and type?

Comment: not generating them all. its just generate a single ball without taking sprite, size or any properties. 

But when i call the function directly, without RPC, it works fine @derHugo

Comment: no wait just to be clear ... it **is generating** them in general. So the instantiate works fine. Can you debug and confirm the `SetSprite` is executed on a client? As said I don't know how exactly Photon works ... in "good" old UNet you would have to make sure the `go` GameObject has a NetworkIdentity so the clients know, which object you are refering to ... not sure how this is done in photon

Comment: @derHugo's answer is correct. His assumptions about how Photon works are also correct. I want to add that you can't exchange unkown custom types without registration, so either send the BubbleType as a byte or int instead of enum or register it. [See documentation](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/current/reference/serialization-in-photon#custom_types).

Comment: @JohnTube oh thanks for your input! I simply assumed that `enum` would would be supported by default and transfered as int anyway